# maven is not downloading iText jar dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, itext7

1) I am trying to create an itext project in my Eclipse(Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)).

2) To add iText7 in my project I follow video tutorial from link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxArv-GskLc.

3) I followed as described in video but maven dependencies are not get added to project. so that I copy dependency code from http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/installing-itext-7

4) then add it to pom.xml file and run project as maven install. but still maven dependency are not added to project. I have attach screen shot of my laptop screen for reference.

[image]

This is another screen shot of the video from where I follow these steps,

[image]

Please guide me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance. :)

here is my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>jumpstart</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>iText7 jumpstart</name>
  <description>jumpstarting itext7</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdftest</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.18</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I have added pom.xml for reference. Thanks

Comment: In your screenshot the Package Explorer only shows the "JRE System Library" but not the "Maven Dependencies" for your project even though it is annotated with an 'M' for a maven project. You would find the dependencies like iText in the latter. Your eclipse project or eclipse itself somehow seems to be in disorder. If I were you I'd first try to create the project anew from scratch. If that doesn't work either, I'd assume that eclipse needs a fresh install. The error messages for me seem to indicate that your eclipse installation is in need for repair.

Comment: @mkl : I have tried it for many times and as per your suggestion I removed my previous eclipse and install new one and this time there is no error regarding eclipse. But still there is same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I had no problems in that respect myself, neither with eclipse mars nor neon. So I'm afraid I have no further idea.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem either. I was the one who made that video and I've done this many times without any problem on different versions of Eclipse (from Mars to Neon).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie : It works now. I think the problem was with the settings in eclipse. Thank you all for your guidance and suggestion.

Comment: OK, thank you for the feedback (and for posting the answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
Finally it work. Here what I did,
In Eclipse,
1) Go to windows tab-> preferences ->maven,
   Here I check the box for,
  1) Download Artifacts for JavaDoc
  2) Download repository index updates on startup.

2) clean All project,
  1) Project tab ->clean.

3) Restarted Eclipse, and Run As maven install. Done.
```